# Can a driver be compiled alone instead of the whole linux kernel?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel

I made some changes to the serial driver on my linux machine. I've been trying to compile the module and reload it, but it throws some errors. Instead, if I recompile the whole kernel it works fine.

Is it possible to make my changes to the serial driver, and compile only that module, and load it in?

Thanks

Comment: Which errors does it throw? Does it work if you compile the kernel, make a trivial change to the driver and then cd to its directory and compile it? (without doing a kernel wide make clean first!)

Comment: I made some changes in /drivers/usb/serial/usb_wwan.c -- how do I recompile just this module?

Comment: Back in the kernel 1.3 era (when 2.0 kernels were just new and I was writing a Firewire driver for Linux (no, not released, Philips Natlab only)) it was just a cd /usr/src/linux/drivers/../something/ and a `make firewire.c` (obviously your name will be different, but ls is your friend).

Comment: You didn't have to recompile it?

Comment: I edited the make file top include the needed drivers (3 layers of them <strike>shamelessly stolen</strike> based on the way the SCSI subsystem works. IEEE1394 net, 1394 base, 1394 AIC5800 driver.)

Comment: It depends on whether the driver is in-kernel, in which case you can only recompile the whole kernel, or it really is a module, in which case it can be recompiled separately. Which driver are you referring to ? Also, why do you want to recompile? What is the need?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention successfully doing 'recompile the whole kernel' you are ready to go without doing recompiling whole kernel again. 
Most of user fail to do module only compile just because not having all required header library source available. Full kernel compiling mean other required lib file in place.

Now what you need to do is issuing:

```
sudo make prepare
```

just after issuing

```
sudo make config
```

or

```
sudo make oldconfig
```

Let me give you step by step command (in dirty way FYI:)

```
>cd /usr/src/linux-source-X.XX.X

>sudo cp /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/Module.symvers .
>sudo cp /boot/config-X.xx.x-xx-YYYY .config
```

Above steps are same for compiling full kernel or module only mak. Now if you need to make ONLY module let your **make** command **'prepare'** itself with necessary change automatically interlinked lib/config files for modules on target to make. Try two command bellow:

```
>sudo make -C  /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ prepare
>sudo make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ M=/usr/src/linux-source-X.xx.X/drivers/directory/of/modules/you/compiling/only prepare modules
```

As far I can remember adding **'M'** switch tell make to compile modules for directory of source indicate with , before 'preparing' with necessary lib/header files.

Hope at this point if everything done properly and make exit without having any error. Now you already have your_module.ko ready to install on module path of your system.

Try:

```
>sudo make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ M=/usr/src/linux-source-X.xx.X/drivers/directory/of/modules/you/compiling/only modules_install
```

or

> sudo make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ M=/usr/src/linux-source-X.xx.X/drivers/directory/of/modules/you/compiling/only install

```
>depmod -a
```

Hopefully your module is now ready for

```
>modeprob your_mod
```

command

If you carefully look on your eror message created by make command when compile module alone, you will get information of ether error on source syntax / mission lib file or it failing other error like missing dependency modules/source.

Happy Compiling:)